# How does my For loop excutes the body without using the initialization value?

Tags: java

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20 ; i ++)
{
    System.out.println("hey");
}
```

In the above code I haven't used i value inside the loop like say system.out.println(i); but still my I am able to print hey 20times can some one explain how

Comment: Why do you think it would behave differently depending on whether `i` is used in the body of the code? The logic of "how to check whether or not to run another iteration of the loop" doesn't care what the body of the loop does. (Of course, if you insert `i = 25;` into the loop body, that affects how often it'll be run - but not how that's evaluated.)

Comment: But `i` *is* used inside the loop, just not vissible to you. Where else do you think the condition `i < 20` or the expression `i++` should be, if not inside the loop?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the body will be executed irrespective of the I variable used or not got this thanks again,,,then what exactly how i  variable work here?

Comment: @SAIRAM It works exactly the same way as if you *had*  used it for anything in the body of the loop.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html this will help

Answer (score 1):

The `for` construct consists of 4 parts:

```
for ( <initialization>; <loop condition>; <increment> ) {
    <body>
}
```

you can think of it as translating to:

```
<initialization>
while (<loop condition>) {
    <body>
    <increment>
}
```

In your case:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 20) {
    System.out.println("hey");
    i++;
}
```

It is your <increment> statement that changes the state of the program and is ultimately responsible for interrupting the loop... in a sense, both <increment> and <loop condition> get executed *inside* the loop (ie: they are executed repeatedly).